# SQL Database foreign keys issue after restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've just had a colleague present me with a SQL Database that has came from a 3rd party company.

They took a backup of the database from the 3rd party and have restored it here in our office.

There's an issue, as it seems that all foreign keys for each table, are actual table properties, as opposed to actual relationships.

I've not seen this before, and was wondering if anyone know's what its original datasource might be? or if there's been a corruption when making the backup.

The guys are going to have to re-map all the relationships, which is a tedious task as its a very large schema.

*** UPDATE ****

An example would be like this :-

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why taking backup using 3rd party tool when SQL server has built in, Take backup using SQL Server and then restore, and check all foreign keys.

Comment: what do you mean by "table properties as opposed to actual relationships"?  like... implied relationship of "tableA.someId = tableB.someId" without actually defining the foreign key?

Comment: @mr_eclair where not using a 3rd party tool, its a sql database that was owned by a 3rd party.

Comment: @Kritner, please see my update. The FK is a property in the table, but not mapped as a relationship. It's weird.

Comment: @Derek aren't they just the names of the foreign key fields ? What you're missing is the definition of the constraint itself. Is there data in the database ? Ask them to script out the constraints so you can recreate them.

Comment: I don't think in taking a DB backup you could ever lose the FK relationships... if the backup were corrupt the checksum would likely catch it.  It sounds to me like they did something like a "poor man's relationship" (i have no idea what else to call it).  It sounds like they may have just not created relationships to make manual data manipulation easier.  Seen it done before, makes me feel dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just because the column name starts with FK does not make it a foreign key.
Are you sure the foreign key constraints exist in the original database?

Perhaps they never implemented the constraints. They should be visible under the keys section when you open the table. See image below

[image]

Depending on what you want to achieve, there might be no need to reimplement the constraints. E.g. some relative small read only queries will work as well. As soon as you start updating I'd prefer to have the constraints in place though.

Comment: I would guess the third party developement team was incompetent and preferred to do everything through the gui rather than care about data integrity out of some misguided idiocy about FKs slowing things down.  Of course I have never seen a well designed database that was part of a third-party product.

Comment: @HLGEM I've never seen anything like this.